# nginx PHP Forward Slash Before GET Params

Tags: php, nginx

How do I configure nginx to allow a slash between my /test_file.php/?param1=test ? Currently is only allowing /test_file.php?param1=test ...

Here is my current configuration:

```html
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    # rewrite ^/(.php*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Url working (undesirable):https://example.com/workouts.php?workout=206
Url I want: https://example.com/workouts.php/?workout=206

Comment: try removing $uri/ i.e., try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;, i would say even try_files $uri /index.php; might work, arguments are passed to upstream by default.

Answer (score 1):

The block:

```
location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

is responsible for processing any URI which ends with `.php`.

A simple solution would be to change the regular expression to accept URIs which include pathinfo. However, you should also make other changes within the block to mitigate known exploits. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```